# Scheduled Request to my website from an external source

Tags: php, web

My web host doesn't provide scheduling requests and the server is also windows so i was wondering is there websites which allows me to create scheduled request to other websites 
example : can i get call my abc.php 24hours from another website?

Comment: Really, I would suggest changing web hosts to one offering more features.  Basic task scheduling (cron) is a very fundamental feature that should be present.

Comment: No idea if it's any good - http://cronless.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are services like this.

If your hosting provider doesn't allow setting cronjobs, there are some services, that will allow cronjob up to each hour for free, like [cronless.com](http://cronless.com), [easycron.com](http://easycron.com) or [setcronjob.com](http://setcronjob.com).