# Running a looping PHP Script on my server

Tags: php, apache

I have a windows pc with `apache` running, and I needed a `php` script to continuously run to listen to inputs coming from a `UDP port`, and take the required action and send it back.

The only way I know how to do this, is to install `curl` for `cmd`, and run the `php script` with a `WHILE loop`. What I am afraid is that this is the wrong way to do it.and may be unreliable and take up large amount of system resources.

Can people comment on the above method? I have heard of cron..but thats for unix only? What can I do?

Comment: I have heard this can be done with windows task scheduler? But that does not allow you to say run the script every minute. the worse case scenario is that I have to write my own scheduling app in C# :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey try this below solution.
Use a bat file and schedule to execute that bat file.

For example in the bat file `executephp.bat`, write this

```
c:\xampp\php\php.exe -f c:\xampp\htdocs\do_something.php
```

save that bat file that contains that line.

Go to windows scheduler and create a new task and in action tab, browse to point that executephp.bat and for start in -> direct to the directory u have that executephp.bat.

For example if u save the file under `C:\xampp\htdocs` put that `C:\xampp\htdocs` in the start in.

Remember to invoke the script even when the user is not logged on.

Everything is set and it will execute without problem.

Comment: I have a question. Is there a way I could invoke the file to open? Say with a url link from another system. Once a user calls it, it will somehow execute the batch file..?

Answer (score 0):

A PHP script behind Apache will always have a maximum execution time, so the `while`-loop should always be stopped after the specific timeout.

You should better use cron or a batch script like Venkat recommended. There are some great services for cron out there, that will do a GET request to your server and run the script. Have a look at this related thread: [Scheduled Request to my website from an external source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14537584/scheduled-request-to-my-website-from-an-external-source/14537615#14537615)

Doesn't that fit your needs?

Comment: any idea how long does it last? I could always time it out and re-open it but I want to know how long it lasts anyway

Comment: Have a look here at the [`max-execution-time`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) in PHP, that is default 30 seconds. For Apache it says: `"Apache has a Timeout directive and IIS has a CGI timeout function. Both default to 300 seconds."`